# Copy/Paste using VBA/Button

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone assist with a code that uses a BUTTON to copy a range (A5:D14) from one sheet (input) to another sheet (Data) from A2. Once data from input is damped in Data (sheet) the data from input sheet is D5:D14 is cleared and then you can input any set of data to the Data Sheet at the last available cell.

Comment: The code works for me.

Comment: Did you already try something?  If not sure where to start then use the macro recorder while performing the copy/paste/clear.  That will get you started.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See Recorded Macro below, note the issue is that I need to paste on an empty Cell in Sheet Data. Kindly assist with a solution
Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False